# Android do PATCH/PUT to server

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient

I'm having this issue and I need to put or patch data to the server. I know how to do a standard post, but how can I do this PATCH or PUT to the server?
The URL to the server is `PATCH to www.example.com/api/documents` and parameter is `doc_id`(integer).

This is what I currently have

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("accept-charset", "utf8");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Request exception:", "excpetion", e);
        }
        return responseString;
```

But this code I think is wrong as hell :)

Comment: This is http POST and not PUT.

Comment: @VedPrakash I know - can you tell me how can I do a PUT or a PATCH to the server?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common way---

**Creating jsonObj and putting json values:**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj .put("doc_id", <put your value> + "");
String response = callPutService(source, password, callingAPI, jsonObj);
```

**This is the callPutService that is called:**

```
public String callPutService(String userName, String password, 
String type, JSONObject jsonObject) {
        String line = null, jsonString = "";
        HttpResponse response = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.
                    setConnectionTimeout
                    (client.getParams(), 20000); // Timeout Limit

            HttpPut put = new HttpPut(WEBSERVICE + type);

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
            se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");

            put.setHeader("Authorization",
                    "basic " +  Base64.
                    encodeToString((userName + ":" + password).getBytes(), 
                    Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP));
            put.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(put);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(responseCode == 200){
                //do whatever
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonString;
    }
```

Comment: What does `WEBSERVICE` in this line of code mean `HttpPut put = new HttpPut(WEBSERVICE + type);`

Comment: This is your complete server url. In your case - `WEBSERVICE + type = www.example.com/api/documents` where `WEBSERVICE = www.example.com` and `type = /api/documents`.

Comment: hmm im getting an error, can we have a chat to expain you the error that I get?

Comment: here is the code that i use right now - did I made some mistake? http://pastebin.com/vMsAPZty

Comment: Where is your put for `doc_id` ? What error are you getting ? First you have to put your json parameters to jsonobject and then you call the method as above answer.

Comment: why is there a username and password. On the server that i use there is a security token - should I add the security token instead of username and password?

Comment: This is for basic authentication with PUT. If your server doesn't need this to authenticate then simply don't use it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53956/discussion-between-darko-petkovski-and-ved-prakash)